# Мой код работает, но иногда происходит 'ContentTypeError' object is not subscriptable на этапе цикла

Tags: python, парсер, циклы, for

Всем привет. Я делаю парсинг сайта через API. Парсинг проходит успешно. Но иногда (>иногда<) происходит ошибка во время обработки циклом. Просто как повезет. Данные парсинга после обработки циклом идут в БД. Сам цикл такой:

```
all_parse = []
for j in range(len(prices)):
    all_parse.append([127 + j,
                      f'{[prices[j]["col"]["Methods"][i]["id"] for i in range(len(prices[j]["col"]["Methods"]))]}',
                      prices[j]["col"]["asset"], prices[j]["col"]["price"], prices[j]["column"]["Name"], prices[j]["col"]["Amount_min"],
                      prices[j]["col"]["Amount_max"], "http://link" + prices[j]["column"]["user"],
                      update_time, "BLUE"])
```

Как можно увидеть в цикле, весь необработанный парсинг идет в переменную 'prices'. И далее циклом обрабатывается в нужный для БД вид, уходя в список 'all_parse'. Если я делаю print(prices), то весь парсинг отображается. Но на этапе цикла >периодически< происходит ContentTypeError' object is not subscriptable. Что с этим делать?

Возможно, если это важно, далее all_parse идет в БД таким образом:

```
(all_parse[j]) for j in range(len(all_parse))
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSPanel\domains\project\python\run.py", line 94, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(glasses=["BUY"], assets=["dress", "boot", "cloath", "shirt", "short", "glove", "hat"],
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\OSPanel\domains\project\python\run.py", line 57, in main
    f'{[prices[j]["col"]["Methods"][i]["id"] for i in range(len(prices[j]["col"]["Methods"]))]}',
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'ContentTypeError' object is not subscriptable
```

Сначала я думал, что ошибка в

```
f'{[prices[j]["col"]["Methods"][i]["id"] for i in range(len(prices[j]["col"]["Methods"]))]}'
```

Но если заменить это на, к примеру 'QWERTY', то та же подпись просто перескакивает на следующий этап цикла

Comment: `subscriptable` - это квадратные скобки, и где-то у вас среди этого кода есть объект `ContentTypeError` у которого эти скобки использовали. Нужно вам искать место, я бы начал с того, что код отрефакторил, например, по переменным разнес, а то всё в одну кучу. У вас и трасса ошибки, наверняка, в эту кучу указывает и непонятно где именно проблема

Comment: Вообще, у вас много лишнего кода, например, `for j in range(len(prices)):` и кучу `prices[j]` можно заменить на перебор без индексов: `for price in prices:` т.е. в `price` будет тоже самое, что в `prices[i]`. А всякие `prices[j]["column"]["Name"]` и `prices[j]["col"]["price"]` в переменные, например: `name = price["column"]["Name"]` и `price_value = price["col"]["price"]`

Comment: Оффтоп. А чем отличается `col` от `column`? Увидел в `prices[j]["column"]` и `prices[j]["col"]`. Первое - похоже на сокращение от второго...

Comment: "col" это что-то вроде главной колонки на сайте, с неё начинается строка в каждом парсинге, а в 'column' уже находятся данные об объявлении юзера. Приколы сайта такие :)

Comment: Верней не так. Все строки начинаются с ["data"][0], а в некоторых строках нужные данные находятся то в col, то в column

Comment: Для начала всё-таки предоставьте **полный стек-трейс ошибки**, прямо вот все строки, и прямо в вопрос их добавьте. Это сильно облегчит диагностику проблемы.

Comment: Готово, изменил немного вопрос. Надеюсь, правильно понял, что от меня нужно

Comment: Да, так уже гораздо лучше, теперь хотя бы понятно в какой строке и в какой примерно операции ошибка. Но дальше пока не подскажу, может кто ещё разберётся.

Comment: Кстати, сейчас более внимательно просмотрел, что выводит print(prices) и заметил, что в какой-то момент появляется ContentTypeError(RequestInfo(url=URL(.... А потом снова идет стандартный парсинг. Возможно, в этом дело? И на этом этапе значения вроде 'Name', 'column' и т.д. отсутствуют. От того выходит ошибка?

Comment: Да, именно в этом ошибка. Определить это место можно например проверив через `isinstance` что в элементе находится `ContentTypeError` или наоборот - что не находится список или что у вас там должно быть. Но как в целом обрабатывать эту ситуацию, записывать ли её в базу и в каком виде - это вам решать.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась. Спасибо gil9red за подсказку как убрать лишний код из цикла и
CrazyElf за подсказску с isinstance. В итоге нужно было просто сделать условие в цикле:

```
for price in prices:
    if isinstance(price, dict):
```